# Can I make a barmode = "group" AND barmode = "overlay" in a single ploty R barplot?

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

I have some basic data that I would like visualized as a barplot. There are multiple cagetories/groups, and two y-axis value sets, where the second set of y-axis values will always be higher than the first (why overlay makes sense in this case). As the title suggests, I am trying to make a bar plot in with R plotly, that combines both the "group" and the "overlay" type barmodes. I cannot figure out how to do this and was hoping for some insight. I would like to do it in plotly, as we have a data analytics dashboard that uses plotly for the other visualizations.

```
library(plotly)

xpositions <- 1:5
grps <- c("group1", "group2", "group3")
yvalues1 <- rnorm(length(grps)*length(xpositions),5, 2)
yvalues2 <- rnorm(length(grps)*length(xpositions),20, 2)
plot_df <- data.frame(xpositions,grps,yvalues1,yvalues2)

# Custom color palette
colPal <- c("rgb(151, 245, 149)", "rgb(99, 194, 97)", "rgb(60, 145, 58)", "rgb(27, 92, 26)", "rgb(19, 64, 18)", "rgb(12, 41, 11)")

n = 1
# Initiate a plotly plot
fig <- plot_ly(data = plot_df[plot_df$grps == grps[1],],
               x = ~xpositions,
               y = ~yvalues1,
               marker = list(color = colPal[n],
                             line = list(color = "rgb(20, 20, 20)",
                                         width = 2)),
               type = "bar",
               name = grps[1])%>% # Add secondary bars
            add_bars(data = plot_df[plot_df$grps == grps[1],],
                                           x = ~xpositions,
                                           y = ~yvalues2,
                                           marker = list(color = colPal[n],
                                                         line = list(color = "rgb(20, 20, 20)",
                                                                     width = 2)),
                                           opacity = 0.5,
                                           showlegend=F)
# Add bar traces
for (grps in grps[2:length(grps)]){
            n = n + 1
            fig <- fig %>% add_trace(data = plot_df[plot_df$grps == grps,],
                                     x = ~xpositions,
                                     y = ~yvalues1,
                                     marker = list(color = colPal[n],
                                                   line = list(color = "rgb(20, 20, 20)",
                                                               width = 2)),
                                     name = grps)%>% # Add secondary bars
                        add_bars(data = plot_df[plot_df$grps == grps,], 
                                 x = ~xpositions,
                                 y = ~yvalues2,
                                 marker = list(color = colPal[n],
                                               line = list(color = "rgb(20, 20, 20)",
                                                           width = 2)),
                                 opacity = 0.5,
                                 showlegend=F)
}  

# Now we have a default grouped plot layout(barmode = "group")
fig

# We can change this to "overlay"
fig %>% layout(barmode = "overlay")
```

overlayed plot
[image: overlayed plot]
grouped plot
[image: grouped plot]
**Intented plot setup**
[image: Intented plot setup]